# Automatically count DB records by interval and write result periodically to aggregation table

Tags: sqlite, aggregation, database-trigger

I have a SQLITE3 DB with following 3 column layout

```
typ (1=gas or 0=electrical power) | time (seconds since epoch) | value (float)
```

In there, I document events from a gas meter which fires every 10 liter of consumed gas. This is (when the gas heating is active) once every ~20 seconds. The value written together with the timestamp is 0 (zero).

I want to automatically fill an aggregaton table with the count of all records within an interval of 10 minutes.

I had success with this query to get the counts within the intervals:

```
select time/600*600+600 _time, count(*) _count
from data 
where typ = 1 and value = 0
group by _time 
order by _time
```

But how would I achive the following:

- run this query regularely every 10 minutes (or at every INSERT with a TRIGGER?) at xx:10 / xx:20 / xx:20 / ...
- write the resulting count of **only the last 10 minutes** to an aggregation table together with the interval end time.

I of course could do this with a program (e.g. PHP) but I'd prefer a DB-only solution if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This trigger will run for every inserted row, and tries to insert a corresponding row in an aggregate table if one does not already exist. Then it increments the counter value in the aggregate table for the timespan of the newly inserted row.

```sql
create trigger after insert on data
begin
  insert or ignore into aggregateData(startTime, counter) values ((new.time / 600) * 600, 0);
  update aggregateData set counter = counter + 1 where startTime = (new.time / 600) * 600;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I found an easier solution which in the end creates the same result:

Just turn my aggregate query into a view:

```
CREATE VIEW _aggregate as
select time/600*600+600 _time, count(*) _count
from data
where typ = 1 and value = 0
group by _time
order by _time
```

This gives me exactly my desired result if I do a:

```
select * from _aggregate
```

It's good enough to have the aggregated values at runtime and not to store them. Or do you see a substantial difference to your solution?